# Creating an index on a really busy table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

We have a table with a lot of `insert\select` every time ( like 100 machines inserting\updating every second).

What is the best way to create an index on a table that can't be locked not even for a second?

If I create the index, i'm sure it will lock the requests, and I can't do it.

It's a big table with 1 million rows+.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such option as `CREATE INDEX WITH (NOLOCK)` (and even `NOLOCK` on a query takes locks, just fewer than without the hint).

The best you're going to do is `WITH (ONLINE = ON)`, which still takes locks at the beginning and end of the operation (both relating to recompiling plans related to the table - see [this blog post by Paul Randal for more details](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-19-misconceptions-around-index-rebuilds-allocation-bulk_logged-mode-locking/)).

This will significantly reduce the impact of building the index on your applications, but there is no practical way to completely eliminate that impact. Also, this feature is not free: it requires Enterprise Edition.